"圧しだしてくる" what does it actually mean here?
（なんだろう、少し気配が違うような？椿さんではあるけど別の色がある）
そんな。
自分のことは説明をしても、ここまで全面に圧しだしてくる性格だっただろうか？
The character mentions the character is talking today is acting differently. Then he wonders what's up.
"自分のことは説明をしても" even if/when he explained/talk bout himself
"る性格だっただろうか？" was he the type/did he have a personality that?
What I'm stuck is 全面に圧しだしてくる here.  From context I gather he's maybe describing him as forceful?

The kanji 圧 generally means "pressure." Here are some examples of words using 圧:

水圧{すいあつ}: water pressure
電圧{でんあつ}: electric pressure(voltage)
高圧{こうあつ}: high pressure (which can describe attitude, voltage, water pressure, etc)

圧{お}しだす refers to a behavior or attitude that imposes pressure on others, pushing them to follow or respond in a certain way. This could involve someone speak forcefully, blaming others, or acting in a manner that makes others feel compelled or pressured.
In the sentence "ここまで全面に圧しだしてくる性格だっただろうか？", the narrator is reflecting on how the person (椿さん) is acting. They wonder if 椿さん always had this kind of forceful personality that exerts pressure on others, as the character seems to be doing now.

この "圧す" の読み方は「おす」じゃないですか？ 一応たいていの辞書に常用外の読みとして掲載されているようですし。「へす」はほとんど古語のような気がします。

@naruto ご指摘ありがとうございます。ちょっと自信のなかった箇所なので助かります。このページで確認して回答を書いたのですが、今見直したら例が見事に古文ですね。https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%9C%A7%E3%81%99/ ご指摘の通り「おす」の読みが一般的だと思いますので修正しました。https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%8A%BC%E3%81%97/ ご指摘ありがとうございます。

確認ありがとうございます。修正されていなかったのでこちらでeditさせていただきました

@naruto 修正したつもりだったのですが、できてなかったかもしれません。色々ありがとうございます。
